# Capture Recapture Method for Estimating Crowds

Tags: capture-mark-recapture

Does anyone know of a study that has actually used capture recapture methodology to estimate visitor numbers at an open air event?  We are thinking of using this method at our annual festival, which has no fixed entry or exit point.

Comment: There was another question (that was more general than capture-recapture), [How to estimate how many people attended an event (say, a political rally)?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4111/1036). The [significance article mentioned](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/John.Haslett/st2004/Significance%20papers,%20plus%20others/How%20Many%20Were%20There.pdf) does not talk about capture-recapture, but talks mainly about the density approach, which strikes me as on its face much simpler. (Heterogeneity in comers and goers to the festival strikes me as potentially problematic for capture-recapture.)